# Elasticsearch - get documents which have a field name

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, nosql

Lets say I am putting documents in elastic search as following:

```
{
"name": "xyz",
"address": {
    "pincode": "111111",
    "area": "downtown"
    }
}
```

I want to get all the documents which have `pincode` in them. Ofcourse, some documents entered in ES might not have `pincode` field.

I tried with something like this, but was unsuccessful:

```
XGET _search
{
    "query": {
        "terms": {
        "_field_names": [ "pincode" ] 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`missing` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-missing-filter.html). The [`exists` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-exists-filter.html) will not work if the field is missing altogether in your document.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "missing": {
                "field": "address.pincode"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "will not work"? Cheked it right now with field which is missing altogether and it returned zero hits (as expected).

Answer (score 1):

You need [exists](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) query.

```
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "filter" : {
                "exists" : { "field" : "address.pincode" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just note that the use of the `filtered` query [has been deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html) in 2.0. If you're using ES 2.x, you should use [`bool/must` or `bool/filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) instead.

Comment: Its not happening. I am using 1.7.1. Do I need to do some sort of mapping etc to tell ES that I am going to search over these fields beforehand? I am new to ES.

Comment: @spiralarchitect Edited the answer, please check now.